# How to use filter in Angular JS by field?

Tags: angularjs

I have `filter` in `ng-repeat`:

```
filter: countries
```

How I can to set field from object `var obj = {['id': '1', 'name' : 'O']}`for filter searhing by which I want to filter?

Comment: Can you please try to elaborate a bit more? I couldn't understand exactly what you're asking

Comment: I mean: `ng-repeat="item in obj | filter:search:name"` How I can to specify field name from object in filter?

Comment: Looks like a simple question, but without clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve it's hard to help.

Comment: I added details in comment

Comment: So, I have object `obj` with fields, for example field: `name`. How I can do filtering by this field?

Comment: You need the filter to be an object with an attribute called name. As explaijned in the documentation, with an example and everything: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Can you share an exmaple? In docs is not clear

Comment: I did this as: `| filter: {country : countries}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `item in obj| filter:filterobj.fieldname`